# Can an application write by default to the "My documents" folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, security, winapi, windows-7, windows-vista

If I create an application that writes a .txt file to  C:\Users\username\Documents\file.txt. 
Will it work? In Windows 7 and Vista? Say...especially if I have a brand new default installation of windows  7 and then attempt to write the file file.txt to the "my documents" folder: C:\users\username\documents\file.txt. What if I create a directory with all permissions inside this folder?
Or...it will work but I will get some stupid prompt message for admin privileges? 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you get the folder path correctly using `Environment.GetFolderPath()`, then you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not assume that you have write privileges in that folder.

And please, **do not create files in that folder**!

The documents folder is for the ***user*** to put files there, not for applications. Use the path `%appdata%\yourappname\file.txt` instead.

Comment: In most cases they *should* have write, but it's a good idea to check first. +1 for not dumping files in user docs folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work. The user has write access to his my documents folder. This is the case even for a limited user. You won't get an admin prompt.